# Template for std::make_unique<int[]> with initializer

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, unique-ptr

The following does not compile and produces the errors in the comments:

```
#include <memory>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T, typename E>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique_arr(const std::initializer_list<E>& il)
{
    //std::unique_ptr<T> p{new int[il.size()]{1,2,3,4,5}}; //works

    // gcc error: cannot convert 'const std::initializer_list<int>' to 'int' in initialization
    // VS2015 error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const std::initializer_list<int>' to 'int []'
    std::unique_ptr<T> p{new int[il.size()]{il}}; 
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr_ptr1{new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5}};
    auto arr_ptr2{make_unique_arr<int[]>({1,2,3,4,5})};
}
```

How could the template be written to use the initializer list directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `std::initializer_list` argument for an array is not `constexpr`.  Its `.size()` is not `constexpr`.

So you cannot expand its contents into a `{}` in any practical way.

You can do this:

```
template <class T, class...Es>
std::unique_ptr<T[]> make_unique_arr(Es&&...es){
  std::unique_ptr<T[]> r( new T[sizeof...(Es)]{ std::forward<Es>(es)... } );
  return r;
}
```

Used like:

```
auto arr_ptr2 = make_unique_arr<int>(1,2,3,4,5);
```